# How do you split strings in Ruby like Strstr in PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, strstr

I want to know how you split a string in ruby.

In PHP you can use the function `Strstr` to do this.

I have tried the following code to achieve this.

```
<%
video_url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zo2vav3dYnY&user=12334&name=sdetyfd"
ind=video_url.index("v=")
V=@visual.video_url[ind..15]
%>
<%=V%>
```

So what is the best way in ruby to do this?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to get back exactly?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: You mean the `substring` of a `string`?

Comment: i want to get the variable (V) value from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're after, but if you want the "v" value from the params, i would do it like so:

```
video_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zo2vav3dYnY&user=12334&name=sdetyfd"
param_hash = CGI::parse(video_url.split("?").last)
V = param_hash["v"]
```